# Ordinal addition proof involving $0$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, ordinals

Prove that $0+\beta=\beta$ where $\beta$ is an ordinal.

My attempt was using transfinite induction, and is as follows

We do the induction on $\beta$ so when $\beta=0$ we have that $0+0=0=\beta$ so the case when $\beta=0$ holds.

Now when $\beta$ is a successor ordinal we have that  $\beta=S(\gamma)$ for some ordinal $\gamma$ so $0+\beta=S(0+\gamma)=S(\gamma) =\beta$ so the case when $\beta$ is a successor also holds by the definition.

Now when $\beta$ is a limit ordinal specifically $\beta>1$ so we have that $0+\beta=\sup_{\gamma<\beta}(0+\gamma)$ =$\sup_{\gamma<\beta}\gamma$ =$\beta$  hence the case when $\beta$ is a limit ordinal holds also thus by the principle of transfinite induction it holds that $0+\beta=\beta$. $\forall \beta $ ordinals .

I'm unsure if i've understood the principle of transfinite induction correctly, so if someone could clarify if my proof is correct that would be great.

Note: My definition of ordinal addition is that of
$\alpha+\beta = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$\alpha$,} &\quad\text{if $\beta=0$}, \\
       \text{$S(\alpha+\gamma)$,} &\quad\text{if $\beta=S(\gamma)$} \\
       \text{$\sup_{\gamma<\beta}(\alpha+\gamma)$} &\quad\text{if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal}\\
    \end{cases}$

Where $S(\gamma)$ is the successor of $\gamma$

Comment: $S(\alpha + \beta)$ should read $S(\alpha + \gamma)$ in the second case of your definition of ordinal addition. In your proof, you should make the case when $\beta$ is a successor ordinal match the definition: i.e., you should write "when $\beta$ is a successor ordinal, we have that $\beta=S(\gamma)$ for some ordinal $\gamma$ so $0 + \beta = S(0 + \gamma) = \ldots$".

Comment: Thanks for that i will update my post now.

Comment: Would you be able to check if there are any more errors in my post?

Comment: Your proof is fine now apart from the minor detail that it doesn't add anything useful when you say $\beta > 1$ in the limit ordinal case.

Comment: But if it's equal to 0 is that not also a limit ordinal and we've had the case when it's equal to 0?

Comment: You don't need to say it. The three cases $0$, successor and limit are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I know that you are only asking for verification of your proof, but I think in this case you chose a harder proof method than necessary. Since $0$ is the order type of the empty set, establishing an order isomorphism between $0 + \beta$ and $\beta$ is trivial.

Comment: I was using this example to ensure i understood the principle of transfinite induction, how would you go about solving it in the way you suggested ?